# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$store.state')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get the bellow error when I run my vue with vuex project.

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$store.state')"

in my project, I created the `vuex/store.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state:{

    user_data: null,   
    is_login: false   
  }
});
```

in my `main.js`:

import store from './vuex/store.js'

```
...
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
});
...
```

in my app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <registration></registration>
    <hr>
    <registrations></registrations>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import registration from './views/components/registrations/registration.vue'
  import registrations from './views/components/registrations/registrations.vue'

  export default{
    props: {

    },
    data(){
      return {
      }
    },
    components: {
      registration,
      registrations
    }
  }
</script>
```

in my `registration.vue`, i used the `this.$store.state.user_data` and `this.$store.state.is_login`, the error is in there report:

```
<style scoped>

</style>

<template>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px">
    <h1>registration</h1>
    {{ is_login }}
    <hr>
    {{ user_data }}

  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default{
    data(){
      return {
        msg: 'hello vue'
      }
    },
    computed: {
      is_login(){
        debugger
        return this.$store.state.is_login
      },
      user_data(){
        return this.$store.state.user_data
      }
    },
    components: {}
  }
</script>
```

I have registerd the `store` in Vue, why there still get this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in main.js change

```
import store from './vuex/store.js'
```

to

```
import {store} from './vuex/store.js'
```

Comment: or in your store js change export const store = new Vuex.Store to export default new Vuex.Store and import store from './vuex/store.js' will work ;)